# Clipboard operation without need of artifical delays using Sleep statements

Tags: clipboard, autohotkey, copy-paste

I created simple macro to swap clipboard content with current selection. But it stops working properly when I remove `Sleep` commands: It does not complete clipboard operation. Just try without these commands to see what I mean.

But `Sleep` commands are more a hack than a proper solution. What if 500 milliseconds is too long – or in some cases – too short time to wait?

**Please what is the proper AutoHotKey way to get it working without `Sleep` commends?**

```
^CapsLock::
    ClipboardOld=%ClipboardAll%
    Send ^c
    Sleep 500
    ClipWait
    ClipboardNew=%ClipboardAll%
    Sleep 500
    Clipboard=%ClipboardOld%
    Sleep 500
    ClipboardOld=  ;clear global variable to conserve memory
    Send ^v
    Sleep 500
    Clipboard=%ClipboardNew%
    Sleep 500
    ClipboardNew=  ;clear global variable to conserve memory
    Return
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the sleep statements from your code, but could only reproduce a problem when the selection and clipboard data were relatively large, like picture data.

I made two changes to your code:

**This swaps clipboard and selection**

```
^CapsLock::
    tooltip loading clipboard
    ClipboardOld := ClipboardAll
    clipboard=                      ; makes ClipWait wait for NEW clipboard
    Send ^c
    ClipWait 30,1                   ; "1" watches for both text and binary data
    tooltip swapping clipboard
    ClipboardNew := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := ClipboardOld
    ClipboardOld=
    Send ^v
    Clipboard := ClipboardNew
    ClipboardNew=
    tooltip
    return
```

If this code is still not working, I suggest trying to identify which sleep statements are necessary to make the code work correctly. Use a divide and conquer approach and a process of elimination by deleting half the sleep statements and testing until you find the statement(s) that are needed.

**Update: This attempts to address the problem described in the comment section:**

```
^CapsLock::
    tooltip loading clipboard
    ClipboardOld := ClipboardAll
    clipboard=
    Send ^c
    ClipWait 30,1
    tooltip swapping clipboard
    ClipboardNew := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard=                   ; reset clipboard to enable ClipWait
    Clipboard := ClipboardOld
    ClipWait 30,1
    ClipboardOld=

    Send ^v
    Clipboard=                   ; reset clipboard to enable ClipWait
    Clipboard := ClipboardNew
    ClipWait 30,1                ; Wait for clipboard to restore
    ClipboardNew=
    tooltip
    return
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can definitely determine which Sleep statements are necessary (as your say, the problem is related to large data or high CPU load) but my question is whether they can be completely omitted while still keeping the code working reliably because I would like to understand the principle. Can AutoHotKey work *reliably* with the clipboard without workaround using Sleep statements?  (Btw I found that assignment in style `variable=%ClipoardAll%` are part of the problem. The correct form of clipboard backup is  `variable:=ClipoardAll` which also acts differently.)

Comment: The answer I posted uses no sleep statements and works reliably for me.  If you want to support arbitrarily large clipboard contents, I suggest increasing ClipWait and use tooltips to let the user know what's going on.

Comment: I thank you again for these improvements. I upvoted the answer but I won't currently mark it as accepted because it did not dispell the magic of need of `Sleep` statements. If I use your code, it works unreliably until I insert `Sleep` before and after `Send ^v`. So the magic with `Sleep` still seems to be necessary for stability. The question whether there is a way without `Sleep` or not still remains open. If you write as AutoHotKey expert that there is no way other than using `Sleep`, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not an expert.  I updated my answer with couple more ClipWaits that might help, but since I cannot reproduce your problem I don't know if they will help.  In particular, I'm wondering if it's the `Clipboard := ClipboardNew1`statement that's not working, or the `Send ^v` statement.  If it's `Send ^v`, you might need a Sleep there as the Clipboard assignment might be sabotaging an unfinished paste operation.  I don't know of a way of detecting when a paste has finished.